# How to properly adjust a <div> width on Iphone?

Tags: html

I am displaying these default-width divs

[image]

Every time I try to make these divs larger by doing:

```
<center><h4>CONTACTO</h4></center>
<div style="width:600px; height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
    <div></div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
    <div></div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
    <div></div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
    <div></div>
</div>
</section></center>
```

One of them gets wider, but it´s not getting centered, even if I use the "center" tag.

And I get:

[image]

I would like to make these divs the size of the first one, but centered. I tried using the align="center", but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just an FYI the center tag has long since been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nicolas try this out.

If you're looking for a fully responsive screen on mobile and desktop, I would use things like CSS Flex box and/or Bootstrap. They can help ensure responsiveness of containers for any screen width.

```css
.wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
}

.shell-container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 70px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    background: lightGrey;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>El</title>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper fluid-container">
            <h4>CONTACTO</h4>
            <div class="shell-container">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="shell-container">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="shell-container">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="shell-container">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        <div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have had tags misplaced.
This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h4>CONTACTO</h4>
        <div style="width:600px; height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="width:600px; height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="width:600px; height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="width:600px; height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="width:600px; height: 70px; opacity: 0.3; background: lightGrey; border-radius: 6px;" class="shell container">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <br> </section>
    </center>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the `<center>` element in HTML has long been deprecated as @Phix noted in the OP's comments. Also what `<link rel="stylesheet"...>` are you referring to? OP had all of the CSS inline within <style> elements.

Comment: @TannerDolby you can also ask what are the script tags doing there!!!! haha

Comment: You do not show or include code snippets for any external CSS or JS scripts? How would we know they were used or even needed in your answer?